# How to send a sslsocket to a running process

Tags: ssl, python-3.6

The first process will receive and send some data (to complete the authentication) after accept a sslsocket, then send the sslsocket to another process.

I know that `multiprocessing.reduction.send_handle` can send socket, but it didn't work with sslsocket.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
SSL sockets in Python are implemented using OpenSSL. For each SSL socket in python there is a user space state managed by OpenSSL. Transferring a SSL socket to another process would need this internal SSL state to be transferred too. But, Python  has no direct access to this state because it only uses the OpenSSL library with the Libraries API and thus can not transfer it.